# not showing DISTINCT record on 3 table join

Tags: mysql

I try following query for display DISTINCT record from 3 table.But there also display repeat user record.

```
SELECT DISTINCT users.sid, users.username, users.registration_date, users.FirstName,
    users.LastName, users.phoneNumber, listings.Resume, uploaded_files.saved_file_name
FROM users JOIN listings
ON users.sid = listings.user_sid
JOIN uploaded_files
ON listings.Resume=uploaded_files.id
WHERE listings.listing_type_sid = '7' AND listings.Resume != 'NULL'
```

Comment: Supposing that a user has more than one resume in your system.  Then how would like to display your results?  If you only want one user to appear, then you must decide _which_ resume you want to display.

Comment: DISTINCT forces mysql to return distinct rows. If any column on the returned row is different (such as any from listings or uploaded_files) then that is a different row and will not be excluded by DISTINCT.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen but how? i want to display only latest record.

Comment: How do you define the latest record?

Comment: Do you have a timestamp on the `listings` or `uploaded_files` tables?

Comment: yes in listings table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making some massive assumptions on the structure of your tables.

Obvious way is to join against a sub query that gets the latest listing date for each user, and then join that against listings to get the listing fields for that date.

```
SELECT users.sid, 
        users.username, 
        users.registration_date, 
        users.FirstName,
        users.LastName, 
        users.phoneNumber, 
        listings.Resume, 
        uploaded_files.saved_file_name
FROM users 
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT user_sid, MAX(resume_date) AS latest_resume
    FROM listings
    GROUP BY user_sid
) sub0
ON users.sid = sub0.user_sid
INNER JOIN listings
ON sub0.sid = listings.user_sid
AND sub0.latest_resume = listings.resume_date
INNER JOIN uploaded_files
ON listings.Resume=uploaded_files.id
WHERE listings.listing_type_sid = '7' 
AND listings.Resume != 'NULL'
```

A bit of a fiddle is to use GROUP_CONCAT to get all the saved files ordered by the date, then use SUBSTRING_INDEX to get the first one (I have just used the default comma to split the files up - but you should really use a delimited that will never be in any of the file names)

```
SELECT users.sid, 
        users.username, 
        users.registration_date, 
        users.FirstName,
        users.LastName, 
        users.phoneNumber, 
        listings.Resume, 
        SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(uploaded_files.saved_file_name ORDER BY listings.resume_date DESC), ',', 1) AS saved_file_name
FROM users 
INNER JOIN listings
ON users.sid = listings.user_sid
INNER JOIN uploaded_files
ON listings.Resume=uploaded_files.id
WHERE listings.listing_type_sid = '7' 
AND listings.Resume != 'NULL'
GROUP BY users.sid, 
        users.username, 
        users.registration_date, 
        users.FirstName,
        users.LastName, 
        users.phoneNumber, 
        listings.Resume
```

Comment: it will also display same result.not as per my requirment.

Comment: Can you post the actual table declares and some sample data, and what you want for that sample data. Then I have a chance of testing it.